# IndentationError: expected an output

Tags: python-3.8

Here I am coding in python for get output of length of any string. If user enter a integer value then print "Integer doesn't have length" else print the length of string.

Here is my code

```
def string_length(word):
    if type(word) == int:
        print("Integer doesn't have length")
    else:
        print("Length:", len(word))

word = input("Enter Word: ")

string_length(word)
print("End of Program!")
```

Here is my output result

```
Enter Word: 65
Length: 2
End of Program!
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `input` in python is taken as a string by default. One of the ways you can do this is checking string is numeric or not.

```
if word.isnumeric():
    print("Integer doesn't have a length")
```